# Does this solution to a real analysis problem on limits need any improvement/modification?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

Let $c_1,c_2 > 0,$ and let $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be functions (not assumed to be continuons) such that for all $x\in\Bbb R$  $f(x+ c_1) = f(x)$ and $g(x + c_2) = g(x).$ Further, assume that $\lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x) - g(x)) = 0.$ Then prove that $f=g.$

My solution is:

Let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. Now, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)=0\implies \lim_{x\to\infty}h(x+c_2)=0\implies \lim_{x\to \infty} [h(x+c_2)-h(x)]=0.$$ Now, $$h(x+c_2)-h(x)=f(x+c_2)-f(x)\implies \lim_{x\to\infty}( h(x+c_2)-h(x))=\lim_{x\to\infty}( f(x+c_2)-f(x))=0.$$ Let $x=x_0$ then, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(f(x_0+nc_1+c_2)-f(x_0+nc_1))=0=\lim_{n\to\infty}(f(x_0+c_2)-f(x))\implies f(x_0+c_2)=f(x_0),$$ as $f(x_0+c_2)-f(x_0)$ is independent of $n.$ As, $x_0$ is arbitrary, so, $f(x)$ is $c_2$ periodic. Now, $\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)=0\implies $ for some $x=x_0,$ we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_0+nc_2)=\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_0)=0.$$ This means, $h(x_0)=0$ and as, $x_0$ is arbitrary so, $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)=0\implies f(x)=g(x),\forall x\in\Bbb R.$

---

Is there anything in the the above solution that needs to be improved? I want to know specifically, if something is unclear in my answer. Lastly, any suggestions to improve this answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ok, I will surely keep that in mind. But can you confirm, whether my solution is correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hard to follow since it is not clear what you are concluding versus what you are using. The conclusions seem to come in the middle or in unexpected places. This is a beautiful proof that could be made more beautiful just by minor edits.

1. Your first paragraph has an "=0" that comes unexpectedly on the right (rather than on the left) and might be simplified as:

> For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have (by the $c_2$-periodic property of $g$):
> $$f(x+c_2)-f(x)=h(x+c_2)-h(x)$$
> It follows that
> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} (f(x+c_2)-f(x)) = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} (h(x+c_2)-h(x)) \overset{(a)}=0 \quad (*)$$
> where the final equality (a) is from our knowledge of the limiting behavior of $h$.

Notice here that I started with the limit of the $f$ functions and ended with the limit of the $h$ functions being 0, so the final "=0" follows the standard chain of equalities. The only significant difference from yours is that you started with the limit of $h$ functions and ended with the limit of $f$ functions (then your final "=0" is hard to understand).

2. It may be better to shift things around in your second paragraph, remove "let $x=x_0$," and use a preamble "Fix $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$," such as:

> Fix $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. We have
> $$f(_0+c_2)−f(x_0)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(f(x_0+c_2)−(x_0)) \quad (**)$$
> since $f(x_0+c_2)-f(x_0)$ does not depend on $n$. On the other hand
> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(f(x_0+c_2)−f(x_0))\overset{(a)}{=}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(f(x_0+nc_1+c_2)−f(x_0+nc_1))\overset{(b)}=0 \quad (***)$$
> where (a) uses the $c_1$-periodic property of $f$ (assuming the limit is over integers $n$); (b) uses the previous result (*).  Substituting $(***)$ into $(**)$ yields $f(x_0+c_2)=f(x_0)$.

3. After your conclusion that $f$ is $c_2$-periodic, I cannot follow anything because the phrase "for some $x=x_0$" is confusing (what does it mean?) and I do not know what $T_2$ is. I will just note that, once you have established that $f$ is $c_2$-periodic, you have done the main work, since then both $f$ and $g$ are $c_2$-periodic and so for all $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
   $$f(x_0)-g(x_0)=f(x_0+nc_2) - g(x_0+nc_2) \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2,3 , ...\}$$
   and we can conclude by taking $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

What you can improve is your writing. As an example, I'll permute what you wrote to show how to improve it.

---

Let $c_1$ and $c_2$ be two positive numbers and suppose that $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ are possibly non-continuous function ssuch that $f(x+ c_1) = f(x)$ and $g(x + c_2) = g(x)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, and that $\lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x) - g(x)) = 0$. We want to show that then $f=g$.

Let us consider the function $h:=f-g$. For every number $x$ we have that
$
  f(x+c_2)-f(x) = h(x+c_2)-h(x)
  $
and, since $\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)=0$ by hypothesis, it follows that
\begin{align}
  \lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x+c_2)-f(x))
  &=  \lim_{x\to\infty} (h(x+c_2)-h(x)) \\
  &=  \lim_{x\to\infty} h(x+c_2)-\lim_{x\to\infty} h(x))
  = 0 - 0 
  = 0. \tag{$\star$}
  \end{align}
Let now $x$ be a number. For all integers $n$ we have that
$$
  f(x+c_2) - f(x) = f(x+nc_1+c_2) - f(x+nc_1),
  $$
and this implies that
$$
  f(x+c_2) - f(x) 
  = \lim_{n\to\infty} (f(x+nc_1+c_2) - f(x+nc_1)) = 0,
  $$
as this last limit follows at once from $(\star)$. This in turn implies that for all integers $n$
$$
  f(x) -  g(x) = f(x+nc_2) - g(x+nc_2) = h(x+nc_2),
  $$
so that
$
  f(x) - g(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} h(x+nc_2) = 0.
  $
We can conclude from this that $f=g$, as we want.

Comment: But is my solution correct? I have made the correction $T_2=c_2$. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: So, I take it, my solution is correct. I actually needed someone confirming it. This is because the previous answerer Michael writes, what I wrote is hard to follow and he didn't get some portions of it. That made me doubt whether am, I correct or not. So, all in all, I'd be glad if you provide me with a precise confirmation like, whether my solution in OP is correct or not. **Am I good to go? Is  my solution correct?** (Sorry if the conversation gets boring as I am not a native English speaker.)

Comment: If you provide me with an explicit written confirmation that whether my answer is correct like, "Your solution looks good" or "Your solution looks ok" I'll be more than glad to accept your answer.